# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 131-132: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, runtime-error

**Hello! Be easy on me I'm learning Python and this is my first post. What is going on here?! The website is built using a python script that pulls from Google Sheets. I all of a sudden started receiving this error:**

```
Downloading: Sheet1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Elyse\Desktop\my_pokemon_stats\site_builder.py", line 64, in <module>
    download_data()
  File "C:\Users\Elyse\Desktop\my_pokemon_stats\site_builder.py", line 31, in download_data
    writer.writerows(sheet_values)
  File "c:\python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 131-132: character maps to <undefined>
```

**Here is the site_builder.py code:**

```
import csv

import boto3
import gspread
import jinja2
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

AWS_PROFILE = "default"
BUCKET = "newsin.it"
WORKBOOK = "NewsinIT"

def download_data():
    
    """Download data using the Google Sheets API"""
    scope = [
        "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    ]
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        "credentials.json", scope
    )
    client = gspread.authorize(credentials)

    worksheet = client.open(WORKBOOK).get_worksheet(0)
    sheet_values = worksheet.get_all_values()


    print(f"Downloading: {worksheet.title}")
    with open("my_pokemon_stats.csv", "w") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(sheet_values)



def generate_site():
    """Generate site in local directory"""
    print("Process data and build site")

    template_loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath="./")
    template_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=template_loader)
    template = template_env.get_template("template.html")

    with open("my_pokemon_stats.csv") as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        data = [row for row in csv_reader]

    output = template.render(data=data)

    with open("index.html", "w") as f:
        f.write(output)


def deploy_site():
    """Deploy site S3 bucket"""
    print("Upload data to S3")
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name=AWS_PROFILE)
    s3 = session.resource("s3")
    s3.Bucket(BUCKET).upload_file(
        Filename="index.html", Key="index.html", ExtraArgs={"ContentType": "text/html"}
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    download_data()
    generate_site()
    deploy_site()
```

**What is going on and what do I need to add to fix this?**

Comment: This is basically encoding issue.
while opening the file you can pass encoding information.
`f=open(file_name,"w",encoding="utf-8")`

Comment: Ok thanks! I'm going to try it and see!

Comment: Where do I put it? I'm a newbie.

Comment: add  `encoding="utf-8` inside all the open() function like `with open("my_pokemon_stats.csv",encoding="utf-8) as  csv_file:`

Comment: I apologize but can you put it in the code exactly where it should be? I am so lost.

Comment: I'm in the process of learning python with a bootcamp and started today. I have been trying to get ahead with the Mimo. I really appreciate ALL of your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this I have update the code and added the comment where I have edited as **#Added encoding**

```
import csv

import boto3
import gspread
import jinja2
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

AWS_PROFILE = "default"
BUCKET = "newsin.it"
WORKBOOK = "NewsinIT"

def download_data():
    
    """Download data using the Google Sheets API"""
    scope = [
        "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    ]
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        "credentials.json", scope
    )
    client = gspread.authorize(credentials)

    worksheet = client.open(WORKBOOK).get_worksheet(0)
    sheet_values = worksheet.get_all_values()


    print(f"Downloading: {worksheet.title}")
    #Added encoding 
    with open("my_pokemon_stats.csv", "w",encoding="utf-8")) as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(sheet_values)



def generate_site():
    """Generate site in local directory"""
    print("Process data and build site")

    template_loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath="./")
    template_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=template_loader)
    template = template_env.get_template("template.html")
    #Added encoding 
    with open("my_pokemon_stats.csv",encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        data = [row for row in csv_reader]

    output = template.render(data=data)
    #Added encoding 
    with open("index.html", "w",encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(output)


def deploy_site():
    """Deploy site S3 bucket"""
    print("Upload data to S3")
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name=AWS_PROFILE)
    s3 = session.resource("s3")
    s3.Bucket(BUCKET).upload_file(
        Filename="index.html", Key="index.html", ExtraArgs={"ContentType": "text/html"}
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    download_data()
    generate_site()
    deploy_site()
```